# How to run container every 5 seconds with GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

I have a container that I would like to run every 5 seconds. I first reached for Cloud Run, but it only has minute level granularity. Is there any other Google offering for running containers this often?

One additional nice-to-have is my container has support for binding in a cache file that it can user for the next run to avoid making a few calls. Ideally I can bind that in as well.

It seems like Cloud Run is not a good candidate for this, since it offers neither of these features.

To me it seems like I have two other options:

1. Use a compute instance, run the container entirely on my own, schedule it on my own, e.g. with systemd timers / cron.
2. Use GKE. I haven't explored this option much but it feels like overkill.

Any recommendations around these options or some options I haven't considered would be much appreciated.

Comment: At a five-second interval, it will be cheaper to use Cloud Run always on. Then you can schedule yourself. Personally, I would deploy Compute Engine and Docker for this type of execution interval if the load fits that model.

Comment: Any reason why you prefer compute engine over cloud run for this kind of thing?

Comment: Compare pricing for Cloud Run executing every five seconds (8,640 requests per month) to Cloud Run always on to Compute Engine. Cloud Run has strong benefits, but so does a plain everyday VM. The best choice depends on many factors.

Comment: What is your container doing every five seconds?  And do you expect you'll have multiple instances of the container running at one time or will the container exit in less than 5 seconds?

Comment: I don't want the runs to overlap so ideally even if I have it configured where run time < time between runs, if it runs overtime occasionally, there shouldn't be two runs simultaneously.

Comment: Also it seems like to use Cloud Run I have to make my container listen and respond on a port. My container doesn't do that, so it seems like Cloud Run is an even worse fit.

Answer (score 1):

GKE standard is overkill if this is the only thing you will do on the GKE cluster. However, GKE starts to become attractive if you already have a GKE cluster anyway for other parts of your system. So agree that it might be overkill in your case. You could look at GKE Autopilot since that takes away most of the complexity of managing the GKE cluster.

Another alternative could be Cloud Scheduler that calls HTTP endpoint of Cloud Run service directly or sends a pubsub message. The Cloud Run service would then either be Pub/Sub triggered or HTTP based. You could store your cache in memorystore (fast) or GCS (slower).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there isn't solution to call an API bellow the minute granularity (it's a limitation of Cloud Scheduler). However, you can create an architecture that allow you achieve that

- Create a HTTP Cloud Task queue
- Create a Cloud Function (or a Cloud Run) that create 12 Tasks in your Cloud Task queue and use the ScheduleTime with 5 seconds of delay. The HTTP target is your Cloud Run service.
- Create a Cloud Scheduler that invoke every minutes your Cloud Functions (or Cloud Run)

Like that, every 5 seconds, a task is triggered and your Cloud Run service invoked.

According to your configuration, the same Cloud Run instance can be invoked every 5 seconds. Because it's the same instance, you can keep in memory (or in file that are also stored in Cloud Run instance memory) so cache data.

It's especially a good practice to reduce the latency of the subsequent Cloud Run invocation (after a longer cold start, because you have to cache your data first)

That combination "Cloud Task, Cloud Functions, Cloud Run" solves your 2 requirements (the in memory cache also).

---

*Note: I'm working to also offer a similar solution with Cloud Workflow (instead of Cloud Task) but I'm waiting a feature release to test it. Stay tuned!*